# parse html table using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html-parsing

I need to read a html page and parse the contents of a table in that. I am using ASP.NET.Could anyone tell me how to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a table name, you can do a Page.FindControl(table) Then loop using a foreach tablerow in table.

Answer (score 0):

See http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

You can search *SO* for 'html agility' for ways to use it.